# (Python) How can I print a variable to a Tweepy "API.update_status()" command?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to add some information to a python script that posts the information to twitter. Here is the code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
import psutil
import sys
import tweepy

#----------------------------------------
# Gives a human-readable uptime string
def uptime():
  try:
   f = open( "/proc/uptime" )
   contents = f.read().split()
   f.close()
  except:
  return "Cannot open uptime file: /proc/uptime"
  total_seconds = float(contents[0])
  # Helper vars:
  MINUTE  = 60
  HOUR = MINUTE * 60
  DAY  = HOUR * 24
  # Get the days, hours, etc:
  days = int( total_seconds / DAY )
  hours   = int( ( total_seconds % DAY ) / HOUR )
  minutes = int( ( total_seconds % HOUR ) / MINUTE )
  seconds = int( total_seconds % MINUTE )
  # Build up the pretty string (like this: "N days, N hours, N minutes, N seconds")
  string = ""
  if days> 0:
   string += str(days) + " " + (days == 1 and "day" or "days" ) + ", "
  if len(string)> 0 or hours> 0:
   string += str(hours) + " " + (hours == 1 and "hour" or "hours" ) + ", "
  if len(string)> 0 or minutes> 0:
   string += str(minutes) + " " + (minutes == 1 and "minute" or "minutes" ) + ", "
  string += str(seconds) + " " + (seconds == 1 and "second" or "seconds" )
  return string;
uptime() = time
psutil.Process(2360).get_memory_percent() = Mem
##Twitter Auth Stuff##

CONSUMER_KEY = 'blahblah'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'edited because'
ACCESS_KEY = 'this is'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'private'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth) 
api.update_status()
```

I am trying to have time and mem variables post their outputs to the `api.update_status()`
Any clue or alternative ways to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's the problem? The tweepy docs say you can pass a string to `update_status()`:

```
api.update_status('uptime: %s / mem: %i%%' % (time, mem))
```

Also, I'm guessing you meant

```
time = uptime()
mem = psutil.Process(2360).get_memory_percent()
```

Comment: This is my first python script, so I didn't know how to make a string. Thanks!